# Flutter how to determine how far out a drawer has been pulled?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I was wondering if it is possible to determine how far a drawer is pulled out at specific moment.

> Lets say a drawer is pulled half way out (compared to maximum displacement) the value returned would be 0.5

I would like to use this value so I can control animations occurring in the background.[image: drawer percentage]